# Intel Rapid Storage Technology missing drives when trying to create a new volume

Tags: raid, intel-rst

I had 2 non-bootable HDDs in a RAID 1 configuration through Intel Rapid Storage Technology. Recently IRST started giving out warnings about the S.M.A.R.T. data of one of the drives so I decided to replace them both with 2 new 3TB (2.7TB) HDDs.

While the 2 new drives were detected by the BIOS, I had to update Intel Rapid Storage Technology from version 10.1.0.1008 to 10.8.0.1003 just for it to notice the new disks:

[image]

However when I try to create a new RAID 1 volume, the disks are not included in the options. I only see my other irrelevant drives:

[image]

I have gone over the restrictions for a drive to appear there and I don't see a problem.

I then tried to create the volume from outside Windows. There's a command line version that I can access before Windows loads, but I can't see the new disks there either. That particular utility is still version 10.1.0.1008, by the way, and I haven't a clue how to upgrade it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are there multiple SATA controllers in that system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is that the Intel RST portion of your motherboard's BIOS doesn't support 3TB disks, this is common on older motherboards.

Upgrade your BIOS to the latest version and see if it helps, if not then you're probably out of luck using them in a RAID with that controller.